# Android activeAndroid get TableInfo.getIdName() error

Tags: android

I'm trying to implementing `ActiveAndroid` library on my project, after read more documentation about that, i get this error when i try to save data on database

```
com.activeandroid.TableInfo.getIdName()' on a null object reference
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.pishguy.XXX"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    ..

    <application
        android:name=".Application"

        ...

        <meta-data
            android:name="AA_DB_NAME"
            android:value="myDB.db"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="AA_DB_VERSION"
            android:value="1"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

`Application` class:

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    ...

    ActiveAndroid.initialize(this);
}
```

DataBase model:

```
@Table(name = "MyClass")
public class MyClass extends Model {
    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String Name;

    ...

    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private String updated_at;

    public MyClass() {
        super();
    }

    ...
}
```

and then using that:

```
MyClass class     = new MyClass();
    class.setName       (classItems.getString("name"));
    ...
    class.setCreated_at(classItems.getString("created_at"));
    class.setUpdated_at(classItems.getString("updated_at"));

    ...
```

Comment: try disabling instant run, there are known issues when instant run is enabled !